# How to get Facebook Long-lived page access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

Following https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/access-tokens/get-long-lived/

and using the graph explorer
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

- I select my app (and add the right permissions)
- I generate a `Short Lived User Token`
- I call `/me?fields=id,name`
- I remember `id` in the result as my `App Scoped User Id`
- I call `/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&fb_exchange_token={Short Lived User Token}`
- I remember `access_token` in the result as my `Long Lived User Token`
- I call `/{App Scoped User ID}/accounts?access_token={Long Lived User Token}`

But all that returns is

```
{
  data: []
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you grant your app permission to access the pages you manage to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe I *think* so, when I requested a short-live-page-access-token while testing. If I request a page-access-token using the explorer now, and click 'edit previous settings' I see my page selected. Also, if I go to the bussines tools, I see my app has the right to `Create and manage content on your Page` and `Read content posted on the Page` for this one page. Do I need more ?

Comment: You don't need to use the app-scoped user id, `/me` automatically refers to the entity that the token was issued for. And if you are working in GAE anyway, you can _select_ the page token right there, you don't even need to explicitly request it using that API call.

Comment: The page access token selected there is 'short-lived', from what I understood. I want a 'long-lived' page access token which you get when you request it with a 'long-lived' user access token. Isn't that correct ?

Comment: I need the `app-scoped user id` for the last call, dont I ? I was assuming that was the id returned by the call `me` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the scope `business_management` to my (short lived) user access token - and then go through the whole process again.

I *think* that's what solved it. If anyone understands **why**, please let me know in the comments.

What helped me along the way was the *token debugger* that I didn't know existed:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken

Comment: This was changed in an out-of-cycle release and documentation hasn't been updated, but the release notes mention this change. Since Sept 15, 2023 this applied to v17 and later, but applies to all versions since Jan 23, 2024. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/non-versioned-changes/nvc-2023